# Is It Acceptable To Get Reference Data From Database For Unit/Integration Testing?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing, entity-framework-core, in-memory-database

Instead of manually constructing and populating my in-memory database with reference data objects mimicking what's really in my database to test my calls to Entity Framework Core (yes I know, I should be isolating the database and not testing it for a unit test; however 95% of my application's logic is all related to fetching the right entities for the right values from my database, not actual business logic), is it considered acceptable to connect to my physical database to pull just my reference data, then populate it in my in-memory database for running unit tests (really integration tests at this point) against said in-memory database?

**Edit - 4/23/2018:**
The odds of me needing to delete any of my reference data are slim to none, although admittedly I'll probably be adding to my reference tables as time goes on. Is it still a poor idea to do this? I figure at the start of my test, I could query the underlying database once, cache that data, and then make use of it in my tests instead of querying the database repeatedly which would obviously be a bad idea because it'd slow the tests down a lot. Is it really preferable to create fakes/mocks of your reference data objects instead of pulling them in from the database? I understand for non-reference data that you'd want to fake/mock those, but I figured I'd save a lot of time if I didn't have to create fakes/mocks for all my reference data.

Comment: No, its not acceptable.

Comment: It is acceptable in case your test executes quick. Unit tests should be quick, that developer will get quick feedback. But loading setup data from external resource will make them very slow.

Comment: Then you need to remember that database you will load data from can change, which will fail